# clip `plot` but leaving plot marks intact

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

In this TikZ picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[color=blue] plot[mark=*] coordinates {(-2,3) (0,1) (2,3) (4,2) (6,4)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would like to clip the blue plot lines to the black rectangle. Of course I can achieve that by adding the `clip` option to the first `draw` command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[color=blue] plot[mark=*] coordinates {(-2,3) (0,1) (2,3) (4,2) (6,4)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, that leads to the plot mark at the edge to be cut in half. Instead, I would like a plot mark to be clipped (not displayed) either completely if the coordinate lies outside of the clip region, or displayed completely if the coordinate lies inside. The result would be like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve that with some TikZ trickery (i.e. apart from plotting the lines and marks separately)?

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ticks=none,xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,axis equal image] % This simulates the rectangle with extremes (0,0) and (5,5)
        \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {(-2,3) (0,1) (2,3) (4,2) (6,4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This transformed the 5cm square into a rectangle.

Comment: @AndréC that's correct. We can use `axis equal image`.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for a pure TikZ solution, without pgfplots.

Comment: @A.Donda oh, sorry. I didn't understand. You can wait better answers.

Comment: @manooooh, still interesting to know that pgfplots does it this way, thanks!